# auto change the background image of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created one div having class name 'top-page-content'. And created one script for automatically change the background image of that div like this:

```
    var bgArr = ["../images/unicorn-bg.jpg", "../images/twistter-bg.jpg"];
    function backgroundSlide(i) {
        $('.top-page-content').css("background", "url("+bgArr[i++]+")");
        if (i == bgArr.length) i = 0;
        var st = setTimeout(arguments.callee(i), 1000);
    }
    backgroundSlide(0)
</script>
```

But it is not working. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you push this example to JS Fiddle?

Comment: yes, but actually i don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.top-page-content').css("background", "url("+bgArr[i++]+")");
```

change line like this

```
$('.top-page-content').css("background", "url('"+bgArr[i++]+"')");
```